# Partials in Liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

We're trying to rewrite our current views from ERb to Liquid and we got following problem:
we have a lot of `render(:partial => '/path/to/partial')` in our code, but we found absolutely no instructions how to render partials in Liquid. The only one solution we found was with help of `render_to_string` but it's just too ugly to be true.

Answer (score 3):

The Liquid way is to use the `include` tag:  http://liquid.rubyforge.org/classes/Liquid/Include.html

(I know that documentation isn't very helpful.  Here's a post that shows an example usage:  http://forums.shopify.com/categories/2/posts/1629)